# Missing package when installing Ubuntu SDK on 13.10 64 bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, dependencies, ubuntu-sdk

When I try to install the Ubuntu SDK on my 64 bit Saucy I get a missing package issue.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone advise how to remedy this issue?

Comment: Are you using the SDK team PPA?  If so, it is currently broken, according to the [install page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/).

Comment: This page has the instructions I was following. There doesn't appear to be any mention of it being broken though?

Comment: The problem was fixed yesterday evening, [they claim](https://plus.google.com/114419073019603780828/posts/79rqhj6Gi7T).  Try refreshing your package list (`apt-get update`) and then running the install again.

Comment: I just tried to install it again just now and all installs ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since *"you have held broken packages"*:

Have you tried `apt-get install -f`?

> **-f**, **--fix-broken**
>   Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution.

Comment: I tried this but got the same result.